# Trying to install node v6, but apt installs v8

Tags: package-management, nodejs

I am running ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and I need to run node v6.
I am following [this tutorial](https://www.metachris.com/2017/01/how-to-install-nodejs-6-lts-on-ubuntu-and-centos/#ubuntu-debian)

> ```
> curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -
>
> # Install Node.js and npm
> apt-get install -y nodejs
> ```

I can see in the `apt-get` output

```
Hit:4 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x bionic InRelease
```

before installing:

```
node -v
-su: /usr/bin/node: No such file or directory
```

after `apt-get install -y nodejs`

```
$ node -v
v8.10.0
```

but for some reason it installs node v8

How can I install v6?

Answer (score 1):

thanks to karel

this worked

```
apt-get remove nodejs
snap install node --classic --channel 6/stable
```